# calling `log stream --predicate` command via `subprocess` does not append logs to stdout

Tags: python, logging, subprocess, predicate

I’m writing a python script which calls the below commmand via subprocess and stores the logs to output.txt for further parsing

> log stream --level debug  --predicate 'subsystem contains "com.apple.UVCExtension" and composedMessage contains "Post PowerLog"'

when I execute this command in the terminal, the logs stream produces output like below

```
Filtering the log data using "subsystem CONTAINS "com.apple.UVCExtension" AND composedMessage CONTAINS "Post PowerLog""

Timestamp                       Thread     Type        Activity             PID    TTL
2022-02-17 17:07:51.336951+0530 0xbb0f0    Default     0x0                  369    0    UVCAssistant: (UVCExtension) [com.apple.UVCExtension:device] UVCExtensionAppleDevice:0x1000005fe [0x7f8sffea0he80] Post PowerLog {
    "VDCAssistant_Device_GUID" = "XXXXX";
    "VDCAssistant_Power_State" = On;
}
2022-02-17 17:07:52.241387+0530 0xbb0f0    Default     0x0                  369    0    UVCAssistant: (UVCExtension) [com.apple.UVCExtension:device] UVCExtensionAppleDevice:0x1000004ty [sdg4566679e80] Post PowerLog {
    "VDCAssistant_Device_GUID" = "XXXX";
    "VDCAssistant_Power_State" = Off;
}
```

However while calling the same command via subprocess, I'm unable to see any of the log values. I just see the first line of output. I want to parse the "ON" "Off" status of VDCassistant.

This is my python code

```
import subprocess
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep


def func1():
    f = open("output.txt", "w")
    subprocess.call(['log', 'stream','--style', 'json' , '--predicate', '(subsystem contains "com.ale.UVCExtension") and (composedMessage contains "Post PowerLog")'], stdout=f, stderr=f)
    return f

def func2():
    while True:
        sleep(5)
        with open("output.txt", "r") as file:
            result = (list(file))
            print(result)
            if "On;" in result:
                print (On status)
            else:
                print ("Off status")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = func1).start()
    Thread(target = func2).start()
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: What logging level are the logs being produced at? I ask because your terminal command isn't exactly the same as your subprocess call, e.g. it contains `--level debug`, which would grab all logs, not just the most urgent ones.

Comment: The script behavior is same if I set log level to `info` or `debug`. or even if  I change the Style of output as `json`, `compact`